# Running webpack with watch in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows builds once and exits

Tags: webpack, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there some way to get `webpack --watch` to work on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows?

I am running [Ubuntu on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) and `webpack --watch` runs once and exits, without errors, as if I simply ran only `webpack`.

Increasing the `inotify` file watch limit doesn't work; in `/etc/sysctl.conf` I have `fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`.

**Update:** Adding the following to my `webpack.config.js` file works:

```
watch: true,
watchOptions: {
  poll: true,
  aggregateTimeout: 300,
  number: 1000
}
```

But it causes my CPU usage to spike to 100%, making this solution impractical.

**Update 2:** There might be some more useful info on the issue here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/155. However, I've switched to working on a Mac and this problem no longer affects me.

Comment: I think these kinds of questions are better asked on Webpack's git-hub.

Comment: There is already a mention of this on webpack's github page, but I'm posting it here since it may also be an Ubuntu on Windows issue, and for more exposure as this is a significant problem.

Comment: Confirming the same issue here with Bash for Windows and Webpack. After tweaking the webpack.onfig.js as in the Update above,noticing the same issue - high CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're running Windows 10 Anniversary Update which didn't yet support INOTIFY file-change event notifications. This capability was added in Insider build 14942 back in Oct 2016:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/10/07/wsl-adds-inotify-filesystem-change-notification-support/

Once you upgrade to a recent Insider build, or to Creators Update which will be released this spring, you'll be able to enjoy INOTIFY support which is more efficient than the polling mechanism that your config change enabled.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Run `webepack --watch` from windows command prompt. I know that it may be not ideal, but it works for me.